# I can rename a file with relative but not absolute path. Why not?

Tags: java, clojure

I cannot rename a file using an absolute path:

I've played around a lot and searched SO and other sites but find no answer.

I have a file "/home/john/test/foo".

In the  REPL:

```
(use '[clojure.java.io])
nil
user=> (defn re-name
  #_=> "Rename a file"
  #_=> [old-path new-path]
  #_=> (.renameTo (file old-path) (file new-path)))
#'user/re-name
user=> (re-name  "foo" "bar")
true
user=> (re-name  "bar" "foo")
true
user=> (re-name  "/home/john/test/foo" "home/john/test/bar")
false 
user=> (re-name  "foo" "bar")
true
```

I wonder what obvious thing I'm missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious thing you're missing :-) is that you're renaming an absolute path to a relative path:

```
(re-name "/home/john/test/foo" "home/john/test/bar")
```

which probably fails because the relative directory `"home/john/test"` does not exist.

To find out where your program is running you can do:

```
(System/getProperty "user.dir")
```

To fix the renaming:

```
(re-name "/home/john/test/foo" "/home/john/test/bar")
```

Comment: Ah, yes, missing '/', thanks and sorry for such a stupid omission!